# How exactly does the Tapper work?

Tags: stardew-valley

The tooltip on the Tapper says, "Place on a maple, oak, pine or palm tree and wait for the reservoir to fill with product!"

When it says **on**, does it literally mean on the same square as the stump of the tree? Or do I need to place it in an immediately adjacent square? I've done the former, but after several days have seen no results. Am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

You need to place the Tapper on the tree, and it needs to be on a fully grown tree (aka no stumps).

[image]

Prices and production time will vary based on the tree you attached it to, but it can take up to 8 days. I've included screenshots below showing the prices  and production time of the different products ([source](http://stardewvalleywiki.com/Artisan_Goods#Tapper)), as well as an image showing the three different trees you can tap.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Can you keep the tapper on the same tree forever and will it just keep producing over and over and over? Does it matter what season it is?

Comment: @ChaseC As far as I know it will produce forever. The different seasons don't matter as far as I know, but I have yet to tap in winter.

Comment: They work in winter too.  I've used them in winter.

Comment: Worth noting that the game won't let you place *not* directly on the tree.

Comment: How do you get the tapper to work because I placed it on the oak tree and I didn’t get anything in 3 seasons thus far I have given up.